# I want to make a collection for cash register,whenever the company collection is inserted cash register store data with ID of each company collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to post data in mongodb name company, whenever I post some data using postman, I want another collection name cash register it also stores id of the company(its like storing data in one collection and also store its ID in another collection)

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to use mongoose middelwares, in particular pre-save like this:

```
companySchema.pre('save', function (next) {
            CASH_REGISTER_MODEL.create({your object here})
        });
```

this work because before save create the data you want in the second entity.
if you want you also can use post save to create second object AFTER saving the first entity.

Comment: I've stored my data in company collection. how can I use object id of my company collection into cash register collection

Comment: companySchema.pre('save', function (next) {
            CASH_REGISTER_MODEL.create({companyId: this._id})
        });

Comment: you have to register companyId into register schema :)

Comment: const data = await company.create({...req.body})
    return res.status(200).json({message:"company added successful",company})

Comment: this is what i've done to post data in company collection. now i want that, when i post data in company collection, ID of company should store in cashregister, as i've already made a schema for register

Comment: ok first where you define the company schema you have to add the code that i have wrote before, the code do every time you create a new company with your code: await company.create ..... make an action, the action i have wrote to you is that you create a cashregister entity too: form more info see: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html to better understand what is a middelware or how to use it in other case

Comment: router.post('/adminpanel', async(req,res, next)=>{
try{
    const newcompany = new company({...req.body});

await newcompany.save();

const newcompany = new company({ cash: companyID}); // Assuming your Register schema contains companyId property field

await newcash.save();

return res.status(200).json({
  success: true,
  successMessage: 'Company has been created successfully',
  company: newcompany,
});
}
catch(error){
    res.json({message:"not established"})
}

})

Comment: when i use the above code my try block is not working it simply show catch block

Comment: I'm still confused, Actually i have two collection company(with model schema ('code', 'name')) and register(with model schema 'code'( of a company)) I want that whenever i post data in company collection, inside the register 'code' of that company also store in my register collection. all i want to do this by one route which is post route.

Comment: pass companyId by params and add it like you do with company is the same thin :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way:

```
const newCompany = new Company({...req.body});

await newCompany.save();

const existingCompanyId = await Register.findOne({ companyId: newCompany._id });

if (existingCompanyId) {
    return res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        errorMessage: 'Company id already exists',
    });
}

const newRegister = new Register({ companyId: newCompany._id }); // Assuming your Register schema contains companyId property field

await newRegister.save();

return res.status(200).json({
    success: true,
    successMessage: 'Company has been created successfully',
    company: newCompany,
});
```

Comment: (node:22248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myFirstDatabase.agencies index: code_1 dup key: { code: "006" }

Comment: This is the error i get when I use this code

Comment: router.post('/adminpanel', async(req,res, next)=>{ try{ const newcompany = new company({...req.body}); await newcompany.save(); const newcompany = new company({ cash: companyID}); // Assuming your Register schema contains companyId property field await newcash.save(); return res.status(200).json({ success: true, successMessage: 'Company has been created successfully', company: newcompany, }); } catch(error){ res.json({message:"not established"}) } })

Comment: According to this error you mentioned "MongoServerError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: myFirstDatabase.agencies index: code_1 dup key: { code: "006" }": Mongo is telling you that you already have that company id exist in register collection, I think you made it unique that's why, so you can check first if the company id already exists in register collection, if not add it to it.

Comment: If you still have that previous error, try to drop your collection, it might be an index issue.

Comment: I'm still confused, Actually i have two collection company(with model schema ('code', 'name')) and register(with model schema 'code'( of a company)) I want that whenever i post data in company collection, inside the register 'code' of that company also store in my register collection. all i want to do this by one route which is post route.

Comment: Dude the code I provided above will add new created company id to register schema model, the reason you're not able to do so according to the error you provided earlier isn't with the code I provided to you, but instead mongo is complaining about having a duplicate key when trying to insert that company id into register schema, because you've created a unique index in MongoDB. As I told  you earlier, try to drop your collection if you don't need previous data, or try to make a quick test  on another db (for test).